# How to insert current URL into an article/page in Pelican

Tags: pelican

I'm trying to craft a unique Tweet button for each article/web page, using this HTML snippet found in most themes' `twitter.html` template file:

```
<!-- language: raw -->
<script
    charset="utf-8"
    src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
    type="text/javascript"
>
</script>

<a class="fab fa-twitter"
   target="_blank"
   href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&text=Hi!%20I%20think%20that%20...&tw_p=tweetbutton&url={{ article }}&via={{ TWITTER_USERNAME }}"> 
</a>
```

My problem is that pelican output processor translate the `{{ article }}` internal variable name gets into its full OS-filepath specification of a particular article and not my desired URL setting.

I would like to used something like:

`{{ SITEURL }}/{{ slug }}`.

But `pelican` computes that as an empty string.

Caveat: I do have `RELATIVE_URL = True` in my `pelicanconfig.py` configuration setting file.

What internal variable names (or environment name) can one used to get the full URL setting (i.e., `https://example.org/articles/first-post.html`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix I can do is to duplicate the `SITEURL` as in:

```
SITEURL = 'https://example.com/'
ABSOLUTE_SITEURL = SITEURL
```

And in its place where `SITEURL` is, use the untouched `ABSOLUTE_SITEURL` in the template files whether it is in `RELATIVE_URLS` mode or not.